# how to move specific observations starting with a pattern to a new column

Tags: r

I have the following data

```
charge <- c('UUW SHOOT AT MV PER BLDG','UNLAWFUL POSS FIREARM','lation Management Report','ARMED CRIMINAL ACTION'
,'ARMED CRIMINAL ACTION')
casecol1 <- c('1922-3','F','F','F','F')
casecol2 <- c('DETAIL','1822-3','','','1522-4')


df <- data.frame(charge,casecol1,casecol2)

                    charge casecol1 casecol2
1 UUW SHOOT AT MV PER BLDG   1922-3   DETAIL
2    UNLAWFUL POSS FIREARM        F   1822-3
3 lation Management Report        F         
4    ARMED CRIMINAL ACTION        F         
5    ARMED CRIMINAL ACTION        F   1522-4
```

I am trying to move the observations that start with the pattern with 4 digits and a dash e.g 1922- to a new column so that it looks like this in the newcol.

```
                     charge casecol1 casecol2 newcol
1 UUW SHOOT AT MV PER BLDG   1922-3   DETAIL  1922-3
2    UNLAWFUL POSS FIREARM        F   1822-3  1822-3
3 lation Management Report        F         
4    ARMED CRIMINAL ACTION        F         
5    ARMED CRIMINAL ACTION        F   1522-4  1522-4
```

How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work with any number of `'casecol'` columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  select(starts_with('casecol')) %>%
  map(~str_extract(., '\\d{4}-\\d')) %>%
  reduce(coalesce) -> df$newcol

df
#                    charge casecol1 casecol2 newcol
#1 UUW SHOOT AT MV PER BLDG   1922-3   DETAIL 1922-3
#2    UNLAWFUL POSS FIREARM        F   1822-3 1822-3
#3 lation Management Report        F            <NA>
#4    ARMED CRIMINAL ACTION        F            <NA>
#5    ARMED CRIMINAL ACTION        F   1522-4 1522-4
```